# Como alinhar as próximas linhas de um <span> à primeira linha?

Tags: css

Eu tenho uma `<div>` que guarda uma imagem e um `<span>`, e meu objetivo é que a imagem fique alinhada verticalmente ao `<span>` na primeira linha e as próximas linhas do `<span>` comecem na mesma posição "left" da primeira linha. Para que fique mais fácil de entender, o resultado final deve ser esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente o meu código é esse:

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.row img {
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="images/icon/image.png"/>
    <span>Esse daqui é o meu texto, e como podem perceber, a segunda e terceira linha não estão alinhadas com a primeira linha
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como podem ver, as próximas linhas não ficam alinhadas. Analisando o elemento no *devtools*, podemos ver também que a largura do elemento aumenta, de forma a cobrir a imagem. E provavelmente, esse é o problema das linhas do texto não estarem alinhadas.

Tentei também utilizar o elemento `<p>` passando um `margin-left` do tamanho da imagem. Nesse caso, o texto fica alinhado como eu quero porém, o mesmo não fica ao lado da imagem.

Dito isso, como eu posso fazer a imagem ficar ao lado de um texto na primeira linha e manter o alinhamento horizontal nas próximas linhas?

Comment: Vc colocou display Flex na row, mas tem que ser na div dentro da row, tipo, .row div { display: flex}

Comment: @hugocsl Isso não fez diferença alguma. E eu utilizo na `row` porque em algumas partes da minha página, o conteúdo da `row` são 2 `<span>` que precisam ficar à esquerda e à direita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só colocar `flex` na `div` dentro da `.row` como comentei, e o resultado fica como abaixo. Não mexi no seu HTML que vc postou na pergunta, apenas coloquei o CSS para ficar como vc postou na imagem da pergunta.

***Edit sobre o cometário do Autor na pergunta:***
Use a propriedade do flex `align-items: flex-start` para impedira que a imagem faça o *stretch* e fique "esticada". O  *stretch* é o comportamento default de um filho de container flex, por isso vc tem que setar na mão caso queira evitar isso.

(se não for possível usar `align-items: flex-start` no container, vc ainda pode colocar `margin-bottom: auto;` na `img` para evitar o *stretch* )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.row img {
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.row div {
    display: flex; /* div com flex dentro da row */
    align-items: flex-start; /* evita que a imagem sofra o stretch */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/24x24.png"/>
    <span>Esse daqui é o meu texto, e como podem perceber, a segunda e terceira linha não estão alinhadas com a primeira linha
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, só que agora a imagem está distorcida pois ela aumentou sua altura. Como faço para manter a altura que estava antes?